# Windows 7 RC License

Tags: windows-7

The release candidate of Windows 7 was available a few months ago, and that is valid until June/July 2010. What's the limit of how many machines you can install it on?

Comment: The Beta release was definitely limited to 3 installs per key but I don't know if that changed for the RC release

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was none as far as I am aware. The License Key issued could active multiple copies. I suspect there would be a limit at around a 100 if any.

I have used my key around 25 times during the RC on different machines and have not had an issue. Microsoft crippled the RC initially so the amount of activations is not a major issue for them.

Comment: I've activated my x86 key for the Win7 RC multiple times also and had no issues.

Comment: Boss is worried about me installing a copy of windows 7 on office pc.

Comment: As long as you are aware that you need to reformat the RC to upgrade to RTM it will have no legal impact. Close to the cut-off the machine will start rebooting every 2 hours as a warning. It does happen, I had a production box do this because IT "forgot" to upgrade.

Comment: "Boss is worried about me installing a copy of windows 7 on office pc." and rightly so, Windows 7 RC is been released to the general public for evaluation purposes, not as a free upgrade for your office PC. :)

Comment: @Molly - Valid point. However we do use it here for testing software on "disposable" hardware. Since we are planning a 2000 user rollout in January it is key to test everything :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, each serial number you are provided with can only be used on **one machine**, although you can (or at least you could) generate as many serial numbers as you want.

Comment: I think the hotmail/windows live account was limited to 1 serial. I may be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need a copy for testing purposes the [90 day free trial](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/cc442495.aspx?ITPID=sprblog) version of the RTM is a more appropriate choice.